# Choosing module installation, javascript or native module

Tags: node.js, installation, npm

I have a module and I'd like to let the user decide which version he wants to use, the purely written in javascript or the native written in C (so he needs to compile it first).

The [npm install](https://npmjs.org/doc/install.html) command doesn't have any option but you can choose the version so I can create two branches: v1.x for the js and v2.x for the native.

If the user wants to install the module written in javascript:

```
"dependencies": {
  "my-module": "1.x"
}
```

If the user wants to install the native module:

```
"dependencies": {
  "my-module": "2.x"
}
```

Are there other better ways to publish the purely and native modules with the same module name?

Comment: I'd ask you first: will you have time and be able to maintain a code in different languages at the same time? How would you do when you release a new major version of the module?

Comment: you about you make 2 separate modules ? mymodule and mymodule-native.

Comment: @gustavohenke it's a little module, ~200 lines in javascript

Comment: @LaurentPerrin that would break the user's code if he wants to change from js to native. He'll need to change all the requires.

Answer (score 1):

OK, that's not exactly what you are looking for, but here goes…

You are trying to find an NPM equivalent to [Gentoo Use Flags](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-amd64.xml?part=2&chap=2), which doesn't exist. The closest thing you could do it publish your pure-JS version and have users directly link to the git repo instead if they want to use the native version.

In `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
  "mymodule": "1.2.3" // js version
}

"dependencies": {
  "mymodule": "http://github.com/mymodule-native" // native version
}
```

You users won't have to change their `require` to switch between versions, only a single line in package.json.

Another solution would be to attempt to build the native version without raising an error if it fails. Then you can have a simple setting in your module to switch between implementations. You can have a look at this [other stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787553/how-can-i-conditionally-compile-native-code-for-node-js-based-on-the-node-versio).

Comment: To do: "without raising an error if it fails", the module needs to be located under the `optionalDependencies` attribute in package.json... very ugly to me.
Related thread: https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/2817